# Time Stamping Email with PHP

Tags: php

I am building an email which will be used via a web form to transmit data to a mailbox.  I am looking to timestamp the XML portion of the email using ISO 8601 format.  I need to get the time the email is sent then convert it all using PHP.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[php manual - date](https://www.php.net/date)

```
date('c')
```

will output the current *server* time in iso8601. If you're looking to read in a date, you can pass a timestamp into the function like this

```
date('c',strtotime('January 4th 2001 4:30pm'))
```

where the argument for [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) is just about any english readable text representation of a date.

Answer (score 0):

which php version do you use?

```
date('c');
```

has been added in php5.

Answer (score 0):

The format `Y-m-d\TH:i:sO` is the same as `c`. Since PHP 5.1.1 there is the constant `DATE_ISO8601` holding this value.